# Refreshing Google Ads for Single Page Application

Tags: javascript, events, single-page-application, adsense

I have a website (hellostory.org) with a custom event that's fire when a user clicks a link. Instead of re-loading the entire page a fetch request is issued, the server processes the `<main>` tag content, and then the `<main>` content is entirely replaced with the server's response.

The reason for this is three-fold:

1. refreshing the entire page content is not optimal for this kind of content
2. my own benchmarking has found that fully refreshing the page is an order of magnitude slower than just processing the rendering that changes from page to page
3. a better user experience, especially on mobile.

Problem is though, the ads never refresh. I'm wondering if any of you guys have had a similar problem? How have others tackled Adsense for single page applications? Any advice that won't violate Google's TOS? Or maybe even documentation from Google on this topic?

*EDIT: To clarify, I only want to refresh the page when my custom "user clicked a link" JS event fires.*

Answer (score 0):

This is being done with:

```
googletag.pubads().refresh();
```

It is against the TOS of Adsense, but you can use it with Adsense + DFP (Double click for publishers)
 This [documentation](https://support.google.com/admanager/answer/1638622?hl=en&visit_id=637254839114636187-1693266570&rd=2) should point you in the right direction

Remember to use DFP, or you will get banned!